# When attaching a process to CDT, how to display name instead of id?

Tags: eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt

When I debug with CDT (c eclipse) I want to attach a Matlab model. This is possible and also working quiet nicely. BUT: CDT presents a list of possible processes to attach. This list looks like this:

[image]

Some of the listed processes are represented by their names, some just with the process id. If I want to find the Matlab process, I need to go through the list and look at each individually. Is there a way to force eclipse to only show the names? I don't care about the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, the best way is to modify Eclipse CDT source code or create bug report http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/developers.php. I'd rather worried about ability to not list all the processes but only attach those which contain binary image that is about to debug.